# How to rethrow java exception in groovy after using gmavenplus plugin?

Tags: java, exception, groovy, rest-assured, gmavenplus

I'm working on a PR for RestAssured. There is some Groovy compilation in that project. Because of upgrading to Java 11, I've switched from the gmaven plugin to the gmavenplus plugin.

Afterwards, tests are failing. The expected Java exception is no longer thrown. Instead, a groovy invocation error is thrown because of the Java Exception. Is this caused by the plugin switch? If so, how to make sure the Java Exception is thrown, instead of the groovy exception? Any pointers/help is welcome!

Test now failing:

```html
@Test(expected = SSLHandshakeException.class)
public void whenEnablingAllowAllHostNamesVerifierWithoutActivatingAKeyStore() throws Exception {
    RestAssured.config = RestAssuredConfig.config().sslConfig(SSLConfig.sslConfig().allowAllHostnames());
    try {
        RestAssured.get("https://localhost:8443/hello").then().spec(helloWorldSpec());
    } finally {
        RestAssured.reset();
    }
}
```

Outcome:

java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException> but was<org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException> .....
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:

Full code available in the branch: [code](https://github.com/appiepollo14/rest-assured/tree/feature/json-b3)